# LateInitialization error GoogleMapController in GeoFlutterFire example

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm studying this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire/example) from GeoFlutterFire in pubdev and trying to run it but it causes this error only at runtime

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following LateError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _MyAppState#453ce):
LateInitializationError: Field '_mapController@144028033' has not been initialized.
```

The error seems to come from this :

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    
     late GoogleMapController _mapController;
     late TextEditingController _latitudeController, _longitudeController;
```

I changed it to late from final. then tried using both, but I'm still getting the same error. How do I properly initialize this `GoogleMapController`?

Comment: Where are you acessing `_mapController`?

Comment: Where are you using `_mapController` in your code? Have you created `_onMapCreated` from the example, where it's initializing it?

Comment: @Nicks101 the code is from the example for the plugin. Didn't alter it except for suggestions to make it null safe. https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire/example  It's called on 'onmapcreated' in the body of the widget tree

Comment: It's clear that `_mapController` is being used before it was initialized. Maybe while migrating to null safe, you left something out. I can't say without looking at more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually in the example. You can refactor it as follows:

1. [In line 25](https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart#L25), set `_mapController` as nullable:

```dart
GoogleMapController? _mapController;
```

2. [In line 202](https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart#L202), add a null-access operator to `_mapController`:

```dart
void _showHome() {
  _mapController?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
    const CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(12.960632, 77.641603),
      zoom: 15.0,
    ),
  ));
}
```